# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Tags: php

I get this error when running a source code downloaded from Internet. How to fix it? It seems to be the PHP version problem. I use PHP 5.3.

```
[Wed Sep 05 20:31:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - assumed 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 209
[Wed Sep 05 20:31:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 210
[Wed Sep 05 20:31:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 211
[Wed Sep 05 20:31:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_FAILONERROR - assumed 'CURLOPT_FAILONERROR' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 212
[Wed Sep 05 20:31:40 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/framework/uniprogy/extensions/curl/CURL.php on line 22
[Wed Sep 05 20:33:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - assumed 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 209
[Wed Sep 05 20:33:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 210
[Wed Sep 05 20:33:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 211
[Wed Sep 05 20:33:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_FAILONERROR - assumed 'CURLOPT_FAILONERROR' in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/protected/modules/location/worklets/WLocationHelper.php on line 212
[Wed Sep 05 20:33:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /home/hieugioi/Workspace/PHP/Couponic/framework/uniprogy/extensions/curl/CURL.php on line 22
```

Comment: check if curl is installed using phpinfo()

Comment: those constants are part of curl

Comment: Hehe thanks. Post an answer please.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Install `curl` and all your problems will disappear :)

Comment: @kwoxer Check if curl is really installed with phpinfo()

Comment: It was installed. Somehow I needed to install php5.6-curl instead of php5-curl... now it's working.

Answer (score 23):

Install `php5-curl`. For Debian, use

```
$ apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 4):

first check your php version wtith this command

```
php -v
```

for example return PHP 7.3.27-9
then install curl module for this version

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

Comment: Thanks. For php8.0 I used `sudo apt-get install php8.0-curl`