# Why error: Google_Client.php on line 106 Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive Quick Start:

`Run a Drive App in PHP`  [Code I'm using](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php#step_3_set_up_the_sample)

I have PHP installed, and can run php commands from the operating system command line.  I'm using Windows 7.  I can start the quickstart.php code running from the command line, but I'm getting the error:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER -
>   assumed 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' in
>   C:\google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php on line 106

So, this is a php file in the Google PHP API code provided by Google.  How can I fix this so I can get this code to run?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282779/use-of-undefined-constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you dont have Curl installed / setup in your php.

Run this to check if its there.  I could be wrong.

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Check your php.ini see if there is a way to enable it.  Other wise you will need to install it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

> Note: Note to Win32 Users
> In order to enable this module on a Windows environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll must be present in your PATH.   You don't need libcurl.dll from the cURL site.

Comment: Your not wrong.  :)  I don't have cURL installed. My operating system is Windows7 Win32.  The PHP help Doc states something about `libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll` which I have in my C:\PHP folder.  I edited the PHP.ini file, and un-commented `extension=php_curl.dll`, then ran a PHP script that checks for cURL and it stated that it's now installed.  That did it!  Awesome.  My command line php script now works.  Thank you, thank you, thank you.